# Facets in marklogic using java

Tags: java, nosql, marklogic, facet, marklogic-9

How to get Facets Information from MarkLogic using java API? I tried to figure our by referring to some docs but was unable to get the solution.
Please help in finding the solution.

I made an element range Index on json Property named "integerQuery" 
         [image: Element range index on "integerQuery"]

Now trying to get faceted values and names from the code.

```
  DatabaseClient client=DatabaseClientFactory.newClient("10.53.195.198",6010,"nosql",new 
     DigestAuthContext("admin","admin"));   

    QueryManager queryManager=client.newQueryManager();

    StructuredQueryBuilder queryBuilder=queryManager.newStructuredQueryBuilder();

 queryBuilder.jsonProperty("integerQuery");
 StructuredQueryDefinition def=queryBuilder.or();
   SearchHandle handle= queryManager.search(def,new SearchHandle());
 System.out.println(handle.getFacetResult("integerQuery"));  //Prints NULL
```

Tried using query options with `QueryOptionsBuilder` but the class was removed in the updated MarkLogic java version.

Can anyone suggest an answer detailed description of the faceted values from element range index ?

I tried to learn from the intro course provided by them but it still uses QueryOptionsBuilder class.

my json document in database.

```
{
  "Name": "Flipkart", 
  "integerQuery": 7
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the Options yourself for facets. Then, use the `StructuredQueryDefinition` built from the `StructuredQueryBuilder` together with the facet options and pass it on to `RawCombinedQueryDefinition`. A sample example would be:

```
// Build the StructuredQueryDefinition 
// from StructuredQueryBuilder
StructuredQueryDefinition builtSQ = queryBuilder.term("one");
String XML_OPTIONS = 
     "<options xmlns=\"http://marklogic.com/appservices/search\">" +
        " <constraint name=\"artist\"> " +
        " <range type = \"xs:string\" " +
               " collation = \"http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1/AS/T00BB\"> " + 
        " <element ns = \"http://marklogic.com/MLU/top-songs\" name=\"artist\"/>" + 
        " <facet-option>descending</facet=option> " +
        " <facet-option>limit=30</facet=option> " +
     "</options>";
// Create a QueryManager
QueryManager qm = client.newQueryManager();
StructuredWriteHandle queryHandle = new StringHandle().with(
        "<search xmlns=\"http://marklogic.com/appservices/search\">" +
            builtSQ.serialize() + 
            XML_OPTIONS +
        "</search>").withFormat(Format.XML)
RawCombinedQueryDefinition query = qm.newRawCombinedQueryDefinition(queryHandle);
// Perform the search
SearchHandle results = qm.search(query, new SearchHandle());
```

The above XML_OPTIONS are for building a facet based on range index on element "artist". For more information on how to build the facet options, please go through the following links.

[Generating Search Facets](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/search#id_27983)

[Constrained Searches and Faceted Navigation](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_77403)

[Constraint Options](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_95820)

[Facet Options](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_32558)

For information about the Combined Query please see this [link](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_50826)

Hope this helps!